How to view Oldest Query results in Azure Monitor Metrics for an Azure PostgreSQL Flex Server instance
I have an Azure PostgreSQL Flex Server instance deployed with the appropriate shared libraries set, specifically the server parameter, AUTO_EXPLAIN, is enabled among the others required, per the azure docs for identifying slow queries.
The server restarted in a few minutes and I set auto_explain.log_min_duration to 5000 (milliseconds).
I have since made queries against this instance that take 6+ seconds to finish. Yet, in the Azure Monitor Metrics blade I've made a query with the following:

scope --> the psql instance
Metric Namespace --> PostgreSQL flexible server
Metric --> Oldest Query
Aggregation type --> Max (only one available)

and there are zero results.
Other metrics work fine such as Database Is Alive.
Is the missing piece to enable Query Store?
Az Flex Server Query Performance Insight

SELECT query, execution_time, timestamp
FROM pg_stat_statements
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 10; try this query once.

As you mentioned you have enabled the required shared libraries, for the server parameter, AUTO_EXPLAIN.
And you want perform on Metric to view Oldest Query.

Enable AUTO_EXPLAIN

Use PostgreSQL client Connect to Azure PostgreSQL Flex Server and run the command
ALTER SYSTEM SET aut_explain.log = 'on' RESTART;

This setting applies to all sessions across the entire PostgreSQL instance and attempts to enable the auto_explain extension's logging feature.
Next, as you asked you want to query the oldest queries
Use PostgreSQL client Connect to Azure PostgreSQL Flex Server and run the command
SELECT query, execution_time, timestamp
FROM pg_stat_statements
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 10;

The above query attempts to retrieve information about recently executed queries from the pg_stat_statements system view.
Once you run the above query you can view Query Results in Azure Monitor Metrics
To view the query results in Azure Monitor Metrics
Azure PostgreSQL Flex Server > Monitor > Metrics > Select "pg_stat_statements" as the metric name.
Select the desired time range.
Click on the "Query" tab and run the following query:
SELECT query, execution_time, timestamp
FROM pg_stat_statements
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 10;


pg_stat_statements is not an available metric in the namespace, PostgreSQL flexible server ...

@dat let me check and update the solution for you.

@dat can you try CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;

To create the extension
CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;
Change in config
To alter system set shared_preload_libraries='pg_stat_statements';
Restart
$ systemctl restart postgresql
Verify changes applied or not.
select * from pg_file_Settings where name='shared_preload_libraries';
The applied attribute must be 'true'.

Can you please check if the above help you?
